# Azure k8s load balancer DNS name

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster, running version `1.15.7`. This cluster recently replaced an older cluster version (`1.12.something`). In the past, once the various service pods were up and running, we would create a public IP resource in Azure portal and assign it a name, then create a `Service` resource like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-frontend
  labels:
    app: myservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: myservice-frontend
    targetPort: 80
  - port: 443
    name: myservice-frontend-ssl
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: myservice-frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
```

Finally, we'd add the public IP to a Traffic Manager instance.

Since upgrading to 1.15, this doesn't seem to work anymore. We can go through all the above steps, but as soon as the Service/Load Balancer is created, the public IP loses its DNS name, which causes it to be evicted from Traffic Manager. We can reset the name, but within 36-48 hours it gets lost again. My suspicion is that AKS is trying to apply a name to the associated IP address, but since I haven't defined one above, it just sets it to null.

How can I tell AKS what name to assign to a public IP? Better yet, can I skip the static public IP and let AKS provision a dynamic address and simply add the DNS name to Traffic Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in AKS `1.15.7`

[Azure - PIP dns label will be default deleted](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/87127)

The upshot is, this is part of a new feature in 1.15 that allows the DNS label for a LoadBalancer IP to be set in the Service configuration. So, the definition above can become:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-frontend
  labels:
    app: myservice
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name: myservice-frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: myservice-frontend
    targetPort: 80
  - port: 443
    name: myservice-frontend-ssl
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: myservice-frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And the service will be automatically assigned a new static IP with the annotated DNS name.

Comment: I have tried to setup service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name but it doesn't seem to work. Does it work with 1.16.x cluster?  What is the address of this service?
http://label.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com?